Printing SSRS reports from a Worker service project
I am working on a worker service project and have an issue where I want to print a report I get from an SSRS server. The problem at the moment is that I am using System.Drawing.Graphics to draw the document from a byte array which gets converted to a stream and the stream is added to a metafile, the metafile needs to be converted to a bitmap and the bitmap gets passed to the Graphics.DrawImage to be printed done drawing the document. I keep on running into an issue on the Metafile where it throws this error: "System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.".
My code is as follows:
var report = GetReport();

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(report))
{
    if (stream != null && stream.Length > 0)
    {
        using (metafile = new Metafile(stream))
        {
            // Convert Metafile to Bitmap
            bitmap = new Bitmap(metafile.Width,metafile.Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.DrawImage(metafile, new Point(0, 0));
            }
            // Configure Print document to be printed 
            printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "printerName";

            printDocument.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
            {
                args.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, args.PageBounds);
            };
        }
    }
}

// Print
printDocument.Print();

the full details of the error are as follows:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=A generic error occurred in GDI+.
  Source=System.Drawing.Common
  StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.CheckStatus(Int32 status)
   at System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile..ctor(Stream stream)

Any help will be highly appreciated even if it is another way to print the file from SSRS.
I tried using a ReportViewer instead of SSRS Url to get away from using the Stream returned by the Url.
